# Collision detector using vectors

Tags: javascript, collision-detection

I have spend hours trying to figure this out, but for some reason either isInside function or collision detection is not working... can some one please say where I might be wrong?

```
function isInside(locA, sizeA, locB, sizeB){
   if ((dist(locA.location.x,locA.location.y,locB.locations.x,locB.locations.y)) < sizeA.size + sizeB.diams){
       return true;
    }else{
       return false;
    }
 }

function checkCollisions(spaceship, asteroids){
  for (var i = 0; i < asteroids.length; i++) {
     if (IsInside(spaceship, spaceship, asteroids[i], asteroids[i] ) == true){
       gameOver();
     }
  }
}

class AsteroidSystem {constructor(){
    this.locations = [];
    this.diams = [];
}

class Spaceship {

  constructor(){
    this.location = new createVector(width/2, height/2);;
    this.size = 50;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please take the time to fix the indentations of your code to make it nicer to read for your fellow developers.

Comment: *"is not working"* is not a good problem description. Please explain what goes wrong (error message, wrong output, no output, ...), and what is expected instead. Also provide enough information about data, data structures for us to be able to reproduce the problem. As far as I can see, nothing in the code you presented gets executed. So that you need to complete.

Comment: You have a syntax error

Answer (score 0):

isn't  `sizeB.diams` an array in line 2 instead of integer?

in js

```
2 < 1 // false
2 < 1 + 0.5 // false 
2 < 1 + [0.5] // true
```

because

```
1 + [0.5]
```

becomes a string:

```
´10.5´
```

and

```
2  < '10.5'
```

is true

Comment: yeah , I tried to put sizeB.diams[] but didn't work

Comment: What is the contents of that array?

Comment: this.diams.push(random(30,50))

Comment: See my updated answer. You cannot calculate integers and integer inside array together

Comment: Also if locations is an array, how can you do locB.locations.x ?

Comment: Not sure what's the contents of 'asteroids', but maybe you need to do

```IsInside(spaceship, spaceship, asteroids.locations[i], asteroids.diams[i]) ````  
istead.